# Show content of layers in web map application

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-server, web-service, publishing

How can I show the layers used in ArcMap 10.1 such as .csv files, in published web map application?

When I publish the map it says:

> No layers found to display

Comment: is this the same question you asked here? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70679/javascript-api-sample-to-provide-csv-files-used-to-create-map-available-for-us

Comment: yes I just removed that.

Answer (score 1):

Having .csv file in a map service is not supported in 10.1/10.2

Please refer to the list of [supported types](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00sq00000083000000)